# Pegar parte especifica de uma string

Tags: php

Preciso pegar uma parte especifica de um arquivo de log, a estrutura dele é algo assim:

```
##################################################
----------------------------------------
Nome: nome_user,
Email: email@user.com,
-------------------------------
,
----------------------------------------
##################################################
```

Vamos dizer que eu precise pegar somente **valor** do campo **Email**, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Tem sempre `Email:` antes e a virgula depois?

Comment: Sim, essa é a estrutura

Comment: E também possui mais campos antes e depois, mas só coloquei esses 2 (nome,email) para mostrar a estrutura do arquivo.

Comment: é um campo email no arquivo todo, ou são vários?

Comment: Só um campo escrito "Email', os outros são outras informações, só pra resaltar que o arquivo é maior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dá pra fazer de uma maneira bem simples:

```
$start = 'Email:';
$end = ',';

$pos1 = strpos( $log, $start );
$pos2 = strpos( $log, $end, $pos1 );
$block = substr(
   $log, $pos1 + strlen( $start ),
   $pos2 - $pos1 - strlen( $start )
);
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/h0hCfp)**.

Claro que para o caso específico dá pra escrever de maneira bem mais resumida:

```
$pos1 = strpos( $log, 'Email:' );
$pos2 = strpos( $log, ',', $pos1 );
$block = substr( $log, $pos1 + 6, $pos2 - $pos1 - 6 );
```

Se precisar testar casos em que não haja o campo `Email:` no *log*:

```
$pos1 = strpos( $log, $start );
if( $pos1 === false ) die( 'Campo não encontrado' ); // ou return ''; se usar em função.
...
```

### Criando uma função:

Em geral, você pode ter uma função para extrair os dados que quiser. Tem mil maneiras de fazer, esta é uma delas:

```
function my_extract( $text, $start, $end ) {
    $pos1 = strpos( $text, $start );
    if( false === $pos1 ) return 'Não encontrado';
    $pos1 += strlen( $start );
    $pos2 = strpos( $text, $end, $pos1 );
    return trim( substr( $text, $pos1, $pos2 - $pos1 ) );
}
```

Modo de usar:

```
$nome  = my_extract( $log, 'Nome:' , ',' );
$email = my_extract( $log, 'Email:', ',' );
```

Veja demonstração no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/0f3Zx8)**.

### Usando canhão pra matar pomba:

Já que fatalmente alguém ia acabar postando, segue uma solução com RegEx:

```
if( preg_match( '/Email:\s*(.*)\s*,/', $log, $matches ) ) {
    $email = $matches[1];
} else {
    $email = ''; // Não encontrado
}
// podia ser um operador ternário, mas não é o foco da pergunta,
// não ajuda na leitura do código e não ajuda na performance.
```

Mais uma vez, veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/TCKwp6)**.

Se for para achar uma ocorrência só da *string*, não recomendo. Parece simples, mas internamente a função faz um monte de coisa a mais do que você precisa para o problema proposto.

Descrição da expressão regular:

```
 /                 /    delimitadores
  Email:                string procurada
        \s*    \s*      espaços em branco
           (.*)         grupo que queremos retornar (quaisquer caracteres)
                  ,     marcador do final
```

### Considerações extras:

- Caso pretenda usar strings com acentuação no futuro, como "Profissão:", e o encoding do seu texto for *multibyte* (como UTF-8) por exemplo, no lugar de `strpos` use `mb_strpos` e configure seu PHP para o *encoding* correto.
- Como mencionado pelo colega @lvcs, caso você tenha alguma situação em que queira localizar tanto `Email` como `EMAIL` ou `eMaIl`, pode trocar o `strpos` por `stripos`, ou o `mb_strpos` por `mb_stripos`
- No caso de querer a pesquisa insensitiva com RegEx, tem que acrescentar a flag `i` no final da expressão (acrescentar um `i` depois da ultima barra).
- Se quiser realmente garantir que a string `Email:` não seja confundida com algo no meio da linha, pode especificar `"$Email:"` como marcador para incluir a quebra da linha na pesquisa, e a flag `m` para pesquisa multilinha.

Comment: Obrigado, irei testar.

Comment: Só uma dica, usar `stripos`, para ignorar case sensitive, porque vai que tem um campo com email e não Email.

Comment: @lvcs Imagino que como o log é gerado por um script, e não digitado, não é pra acontecer isso nunca, mas vale como observação se for usado em outro contexto. Seria o caso de usar mb_str(i)pos também se for usar com UTF-8 e strings acentuadas também. Talvez eu dê uma editada depois, e acrescento essas duas observações.

Comment: @lvcs editei e acrescentei algumas observações no final, incluindo sua recomendação.